# Login to server without enter user password

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I want to enter the password of the ssh-key and enter the server
But now I am entering the password of the user server

I have adapted my public key to the server using `ssh-copy-id`, but I still get prompted for a password.

Client: `cat .ssh/config`

```
Host alimd
    HostName srv1.mihandoost.com
    Port 22

Host *
    Compression yes
    User root
    HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Server: `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

Client: `ssh -vvv root@srv1.mihandoost.com`

```
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/njfamirm/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'srv1.mihandoost.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/njfamirm/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mvtTfk3TDAkKFPtV4ReA9pvcMwDLlkCU3RpqsPfu3SM explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/njfamirm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:mvtTfk3TDAkKFPtV4ReA9pvcMwDLlkCU3RpqsPfu3SM explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@srv1.mihandoost.com's password:
```

thanks!

Comment: `receive packet: type 51` is authentication fails. You offered your key, it won't accept it. Your user at the remote host doesn't have the public part of that key in its `.ssh/authorized-keys`. If it seems to, you might have encoding trouble, be sure it's utf-8 or plain ascii.  Since both you and the server are willing to use passwords, rather than reject the login it's asking for a password.

Comment: i use ssh-copy-id to add my key again, but not work

Comment: ssh-copy-id copies them to your own user by default. You're signing on as root on the server, you need those in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` if root's home is the usual place.

Comment: yes, it's that place

Comment: last possibility I can think of: permissions. Brute force is `chmod -R go-rwx /root/.ssh`, read the manpages for where and how much you can relax that if you care to.

Comment: edit : say `find /root/.ssh -ls` and include the output to check.

Comment: ```srv1:~/.ssh# ls -ltrh
total 4K
-rw-------    1 root     root        1.6K Jun 27 05:18 authorized_keys
```

Comment: It works on someone else's computer
Probably a problem with my personal system rather than the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137367/discussion-between-njfamirm-and-jthill).